# Mongodb: Need to aggregate and perform deduplication considering a nested value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm looking to execute an aggregation in mongodb that can tell me which documents have duplicate matches based off of a value in a nested field that contains a collection.  A simplification of the document that I'm working with looks like this;

```
{
    "field":"some value",
    "emails":[
        {
            "emailAddress":"example@testing.com"
        }
}
```

In order to dedup, I need to execute an aggregation that can tell me of all of the documents in the collection that share the same email address.  To be clear, not with this example document specifically of course, I mean collect all documents that have at least one other companion document that shares the email address value.  Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(OP expanded the question)
So given some input data like this:

```
var d = [
     { "fld":"X", "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"example@testing.com"} ]}
     ,{ "fld":"Y", "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"example2@testing.com"} ]}
     ,{ "fld":-5, "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"example@testing.com"}, {"emailAddress":"a@b.com"} ]}
     ,{ "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"a@b.com"}, {"emailAddress":"corn@dog.com"} ]}
     ,{ "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"zip@b.com"}, {"emailAddress":"corn@dog.com"} ]}
     ,{ "fld":"Q", "emails":[ {"emailAddress":"zzz@b.com"}, {"emailAddress":"a@b.com"} ]}
    ];
```

This does the trick.  `$match` on existence of `fld` works regardless of the type of value.  You don't necessarily have to exclude the other fields (by `$projecting` only emails) but that trims out excess/unneeded data from flowing thru the pipeline.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$match: {"fld": {$exists: true}}  // only process docs where field fld exists
  ,{$project: {"emails":1}}
  ,{$unwind: "$emails"}
  ,{$group: {_id:"$emails.emailAddress", n:{$sum:1}, docs: {$push: "$_id"}}}
  ,{$match: {n: {$gt:1}}}
                ]);
```

This yields:

```
{
  "_id" : "a@b.com",
  "n" : 2,
  "docs" : [
    ObjectId("59d2d69274d1e2d00ebec06f"),
    ObjectId("59d2d69274d1e2d00ebec072")
  ] 
}
{
  "_id" : "example@testing.com",
  "n" : 2,
  "docs" : [
    ObjectId("59d2d69274d1e2d00ebec06d"),
    ObjectId("59d2d69274d1e2d00ebec06f")
  ]
}
```

Comment: This was an excellent, respose Buzz, thank you.  Brief follow-up question, if I wanted to ensure that only documents that contained a specific field were included in these results, how would I apply that type of filter?

Comment: @mmarbles  A specific field (i.e. field name exists in doc) or a specific value for a field?

Comment: The former, a specific field.

Comment: @mrmarbles   Example modified; see above